# lm() function in R

Tags: r, regression

This is kind of a follow-up question from this post: [Gradient descent vs lm() function in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25949/gradient-descent-vs-lm-function-in-r)

Is there any literature available for the QR decomposition concept involved in the `lm()` function in R?

Comment: It is a pretty common decomposition in linear algebra [QR Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)

Answer (score 5):

As Benjamin has commented (+1) the [*QR* decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) is extensively used and studied regarding its use for solving least squares problems. Book-wise I have used the following books in the past:

1. [Matrix Computations](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/GVL4/golubandvanloan.htm) by Golub and van Loan (*the reference book* on the subject)
2. [Numerical Methods for Least Squares Problems](http://www.mai.liu.se/~akbjo/LSPbook.html) by Bjõrck (quite computational and to the point but strictly speaking not statistically minded)
3. [Matrix Algebra From a Statistician's Perspective](http://www.springer.com/statistics/statistical+theory+and+methods/book/978-0-387-94978-9) by Harville (great book that probably covers all essential parts of dealing with matrices a statistician should know)

I think these books will probably cover most aspects one might care for regarding the usage *QR* decompositions for linear models. Please note that all three books mentioned do assume some basic knowledge of linear algebra (nothing hard-core); if you do not have that I recommend going through/looking up [Introduction to Linear Algebra](http://math.mit.edu/linearalgebra/) by Strang. It is quite manageable and gets you up to speed with what you will need for more advanced applications without being overly mathematical about it.

Ah, and this thread: [Reference book for linear algebra applied to statistics?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21346/what-is-a-good-reference-book-for-the-matrix-algebra-linear-algebra-used-a-lot-i) might also come in handy when looking for references.

Comment: Do you also have some good reference for generalised linear models that you suggest?

Comment: @Steve: In the past I have used as references the books: [An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584889502) by Dobson and Barnett and [Generalized Linear Models](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9780412317606) (uber-classic) by McCullagh and Nelder. I also really liked the exposition of GLMMs in [Generalized Linear Mixed Models: Modern Concepts, Methods and Applications](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781439815120) by Stroup. I have nothing "heavy" on Lin. Algebra though.