# How does R's lm algorithm handle factors

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear-model, ordinal-data

I thought they use discriminant analysis as discribed e.g. in chapter 4.4. in James et. al. "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R". 
But after input from this [article](http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2016/07/20/lm-in-R.html)
and this [SO-question including reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56953563/5784831) it seems that

- a matrix model is calculated in `ans <- .External2(C_modelmatrix, t, data)` (in `model.matrix.default`)
- the matrix model goes into `z <- .Call(C_Cdqrls, x, y, tol, FALSE)` and I did not expect, that linear regression and discriminant analysis are the same on the maths level.

From [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/175984/209028) it seems, **R can always use the standard algorithm based on qr-factorization.

Is that true?**

Comment: R's help `?lm` references Chambers, J. M. (1992) Linear models. Chapter 4 of Statistical Models in S eds J. M. Chambers and T. J. Hastie, Wadsworth & Brooks/Cole. But I do not have access to the book.

Comment: I don't really know what you are asking. R transforms factors into dummy variables before processing if that is what you are asking?

Comment: @user2974951 This step seems to be clear now. The question is what happens afterwards? It seems, the coefficients $\widehat{\beta}$ are calculated from $\widehat{\beta}=(X^TX)X^TY$. Thus, R has implemented a different algorithm than I thought... (And I cannot have a look at the cited reference to check :-( )

Comment: @FransRodenburg not really, `lm` calls `lm.fit` (line 68), then `lm.fit` calls `.Call(C_Cdqrls, ...)` in line 114. Thus "the work" is done in a C function called `Cdqrls`. There I could not check, as I could not find the code. However, as stated in the links above, this function seems to use qr-decomposition, which I did not expect in the case of factors present.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an answer. I think he just doesn't want to include more math than he deems necessary for ISLR. In ESL, QR-decomposition *is* covered (3.2.3).

Comment: An useful reference is the detailed explanation on [coding matrices](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/codingMatrices/vignettes/codingMatrices.pdf) provided by Bill Venables.

Comment: @Yves Thanks for your hint. Really well written. If you like, you can add something in that direction as additional answer. It just explains how the $X$ matrices are build and the picture in my comment is quite oversimplified in case of factor predictors. Furthermore it explains some fallacies: "In R the familiar stats package functions contr.treatment, contr.poly, contr.sum and contr.helmert all generate coding matrices,  and not necessarily contrast matrices as the names might suggest."

Comment: @Christoph OK, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have factors, a call is first made to `model.matrix`, to turn your formula into a design matrix $\mathbf{X}$ and a response $\mathbf{y}$. For factors that just means that the design matrix gets an extra $k−1$ columns, where $k$ is the number of categories in the factor. The reference category coincides with the intercept to prevent perfect colinearity and hence the $−1$. From there QR decomposition works no different than if it were only continuous variables.

For a factor, the first category in `levels(your_factor)` is the reference level, and you could change that if needed with `relevel(your_factor, "reference category")`.

As to your comment on why ISLR skips over QR-decomposition, I searched through the book for 'decomposition' and found this quote in chapter 10:

> Problem (10.3) can be solved via an eigen decomposition, a standard
>   technique in linear algebra, but details are outside of the scope of
>   this book.

So I guess the answer is as simple as: Because they don't want to linger on details that aren't crucial to beginners. Remember that ISLR has a more advanced, also free version: The Elements of Statistical Learning (different authors, but *very* similar style). In ESL, QR-decomposition is covered in 3.2.3 (specifically, page 55). :)

Comment: Now i have a good start in the day :-)

Comment: If you like, you can post a summary of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56953563/5784831) and I will accept. I think this really answers the original  question about coding...

Comment: I just realized, that my question might not be clear enough: When talking about a linear model $y \sim x$, factor levels in $x$ are handled as you discribe. If in contrast the response $y$ is a factor, `lm` throws an error and discriminant analysis is necessary using e.g. `glm`.

Comment: When the outcome has two categories, you can use a binomial GLM, yes. If it has even more, you should look into multinomial regression, or ordinal regression if there is a logical order to the categories. Note that GLMs are usually fitted by iteratively reweighted least squares.

Answer (score 2):

A very useful resource is the document [Coding Matrices, Contrast
Matrices and Linear
Models](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/codingMatrices/vignettes/codingMatrices.pdf)
by Bill Venables, available on CRAN. This explains in details how the
model matrix of a `lm` or `glm` is built, including the case where
some of the predictors are factors. The key functions `contr.poly`,
`contr.sum`, `contr.treatment`, `contr.helmert` are illustrated.

Once the model matrix is built, the estimation uses the QR
decomposition as it can be seen from the [source code of
`lm`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/lm.R).